# How to clean grout over grout?

Tags: tile, grout

We are doing over our bathroom.  We have tiled the shower with large white tiles with a gray strip down each side.  After we grouted the white tiles (waited a couple of days) we used gray grout for the strip down the sides.  The gray grout got onto the white grout, we washed some off but still a grayish colour.  My question is how to clean the white grout? I thought about bleach but think it may be too string for new grout.

Comment: You'll probably have to chip it out and re-do it.

Comment: If you do gouge out the grout to re-do it, maybe mask off one color grout as you do the other. Not sure if painter's tape will be good enough, but you just need to make sure grout doesn't contact grout, since it will stick.

Answer (score 3):

I seriously doubt that you will remove the dye from the grout using any method. Your best bet is to pick up a grout saw at lowes or home depot for about seven dollars that has a diamond blade on the end. You will be able to use the pointed end to file down the small amount where the gray overlapped( if that's what happened). IF it was too wet and these colors bled, then file down into the grout where it bled, mix your grout a little tacky instead of loose and touch up the edge.

[image]